# A problem on nowhere dense sets in metric spaces.

Tags: proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I found a problem related to nowhere dense sets in my metric space text.The problem is as follows,I just want to verify if my proof is fine and if there is any easier way to do it.

Suppose $X$ is a metric space such that every point of $X$ is a limit point of $X$ and $A$ be a discrete set in $X$.Show that $A$ is nowhere dense.

Proof: Suppose $U$ is a non-empty open set in $X$,if $U\cap A=\phi$ then we have nothing to do.If $U\cap A\neq \phi$ then take and element $a\in A\cap U$.Since $U$ is open ,so $\exists\epsilon_0>0$ such that $B(a,\epsilon_0)\subset U$.Also $A$ is a discrete set.So,$\exists \epsilon_1>0$ such that $B(a,\epsilon_1)\cap A=\{a\}$.Take $\epsilon=\min \{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1\}$ and consider $B(a,\epsilon)$.Then this ball contains no point of $A$ other than $a$ but since $a$ is a limit point of $X$,so $\exists x\in X$ such that $x\in B(a,\epsilon/2)$ other than $x$.Now we take $z\in B(x,\epsilon/2)$,then $d(x,z)<\epsilon/2$.Now $d(a,z)\leq d(a,x)+d(x,z)<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon\implies z\in B(a,\epsilon)$.So,$B(x,\epsilon/2)\subset B(a,\epsilon)$.But $B(x,r)\cap A=\phi$,where $r=\min\{d(x,a),\epsilon/2)$.So,$A$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: I suggest using either `\emptyset` ($\emptyset$) or `\varnothing` ($\varnothing$) instead of $\phi$ to represent the empty set.

Comment: "Nowhere dense" means that the closure of $A$ has empty interior. But that does not appear to be what you are proving. Can you state what characterization of nowhere dense sets you are making use of here? It isn't clear to me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair An equivalent characterisation of Nowhere dense sets is given any non-empty of open set $U$ ,I can find an non empty open set $V\subset U$ which does not intersect $A$.

Comment: A shorter proof then is to note that $B(a, \epsilon) \setminus \{a\}$ is an open subset of $U$ disjoint from $A$ (and is non-empty because of the limit point condition). That said, your proof appears to be correct.